# Software Development Costs Pyramid

Tags: software-quality

A friend was telling me the other day that there is a pyramid for the costs of fixing a problem in the software development life cycle.  Where could I find this?

He was referring to the cost of fixing a problem.

For example,

> To fix a problem at the requirements stage costs 1.
>
> To fix a problem at the development stage costs 10.
>
> To fix a problem at the testing stage costs 100
>
> To fix a problem at the production stage costs 1000.

(These numbers are just examples)

I would be interested in seeing more about this if anyone has references.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about deployment cost

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a project, not programming.

Comment: I originally asked this question but it's closed now so I can't add an answer.  I came across the following chart in "Best Kept Secrets of Peer Code Review" page 123 from a study at IBM. 
Phase - Cost to fix
Requirements - $0
Design - $45
Development - $275
QA/Test - $33,000
Customer - $141,000

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The Incredible Rate of Diminishing Returns of Fixing Software Bugs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731150816/http://superwebdeveloper.com/2009/11/25/the-incredible-rate-of-diminishing-returns-of-fixing-software-bugs/)

[image: Stefan Priebsh: OOP and Design Patterns: Codeworks DC in September 2009]

(Stefan Priebsh: OOP and Design Patterns: Codeworks DC in September 2009)

Answer (score 13):

This is a well-known result in empirical software engineering that has been replicated and verified over and over again in countless studies. Which is very rare in software engineering, unfortunately: most software engineering "results" are basically hearsay, anecdotes, guesses, opinions, wishful thinking or just plain lies. In fact, most software engineering probably doesn't deserve the "engineering" brand.

Unfortunately, despite being one of the most solid, most scientifically and statistically sound, most heavily researched, most widely verified, most often replicated results of software engineering, it is also wrong.

The problem is that all of those studies do not control their variables properly. If you want to measure the effect of a variable, you have to be *very* careful to change *only* that *one* variable and that the other variables don't change *at all*. Not "change a few variables", not "minimize changes to other variables". "Only one" and the others "not at all".

Or, in the brilliant Zed Shaw's words: ["If you want to measure something, then don't measure other shit"](http://web.archive.org/web/20140825165331/https://zedshaw.com/essays/programmer_stats.html).

In this particular case, they did *not* just measure in which phase (requirements, analysis, architecture, design, implementation, testing, maintenance) the bug was found, they *also* measured how *long* it stayed in the system. And it turns out that the phase is pretty much irrelevant, all that matters is the time. It's important that bugs be found *fast*, not in which phase.

This has some interesting ramifications: if it is important to find bugs *fast*, then why wait so long with the phase that is most likely to find bugs: testing? Why not put the testing at the *beginning*?

The problem with the "traditional" interpretation is that it leads to inefficient decisions. Because you assume you need to find all bugs during the requirements phase, you drag out the requirements phase unnecessarily long: you can't *run* requirements (or architectures, or designs), so *finding* a bug in something that you cannot even *execute* is freaking *hard*! Basically, while *fixing* bugs in the requirements phase is cheap, *finding* them is expensive.

If, however, you realize that it's not about finding the bugs *in the earliest possible phase*, but rather about finding the bugs *at the earliest possible time*, then you can make adjustments to your process, so that you move the phase in which *finding* bugs is cheapest (testing) to the point in time where *fixing* them is cheapest (the very beginning).

---

Note: I am well aware of the irony of ending a rant about not properly applying statistics with a completely unsubstantiated claim. Unfortunately, I lost the link where I read this. Glenn Vanderburg also mentioned this in his "[*Real Software Engineering*](http://confreaks.net/videos/282-lsrc2010-real-software-engineering/)" talk at the Lone Star Ruby Conference 2010, but AFAICR, he didn't cite any sources, either.

If anybody knows any sources, *please* let me know or edit my answer, or even just *steal* my answer. (If you can find a source, you deserve all the rep!)

Comment: I work at a company that basically spends no time in the requirements phase (and the closest approximation to our development process is waterfall...). Ignoring this leads to so many changes that the software we initially started writing has no similarity to the end product... and it costs a ton more. On top of that, since we don't spend time in requirements we end up making a lot of changes to production after the fact that are not easy to implement because of the way the software was structured around the requirements...

Answer (score 3):

See pages 42 and 43 of [this presentation](http://www.construx.com/File.ashx?cid=912) (pdf).

Unfortunately the situation is as Jörg depicts, in fact somewhat worse: most of the references cited in this document strike me as bogus, in the sense that the paper cited either is not original research, or does not contain words supporting the claim being made, or - in the case of the [1998 paper about Hughes](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/reports/98tr006.pdf) (p54) - contains measurements that *in fact* contradict what is implied by the curve in p42 of the presentation: different shape of the curve, and a modest x5 to x10 factor of cost-to-fix between the requirements phase and the functional test phase (and actually decreasing in system test and maintenance).

Comment: The linked pdf is no longer available.  Do you have a new link for it?

Comment: Try this http://seaspin.org/files/folders/205/download.aspx or this http://seaspin.org/files/folders/22/download.aspx

Comment: Also I recommend my book: http://leanpub.com/leprechauns with much more on the topic

Comment: I just read your book and it made me think of this question I asked 13 years ago.  Then I came here to find you had replied.  Thanks for your book!

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of it being called a pyramid before, and that seems a bit upside-down to me! Still, the central thesis is widely considered to be correct. just thick about it, the costs of fixing a bug in alpha stage are often trivial. By beta stage it might take a bit more debugging and user reports. After shipping it could be very expensive. a whole new version has to be created, you have to worry about breaking in-production code and data, there may also be lost sales due to the bug?

Answer (score -1):

Try this [article](http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200501/20050127-TheDeveloperTestingParadox.html). It uses the "cost pyramid" argument (no naming it), among others.

Comment: Please include an actual answer, instead of posting sole link. Thanks.